# Use of Generics during validation

Tags: java, validation, generics

I am using apache CXF.

The following API is used to post a Contact.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
ResponseResult create(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @Context Request request, @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
        UserContact contact) throws MDMException;
```

Here the UserContact class contains the contact information about a user which is passed as JSON in the body.

I need to do some business validations on this UserContact object. But I do not like to have too much validation code packed in a single class.

**I would like to do something like the following. But I am facing issue with Generics.**

```
interface Rule<S>
{
    void applyRule(S s)throws Exception;
}

interface Validatable
{
    void validate() throws Exception;
}

public class MyValidator
{
    private HashMap<? extends Rule ,?> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void validate() throws Exception
    {
        for(Rule rule : map.keySet())
        {
            rule.applyRule(map.get(rule));
        }
    }

    public <S> void addRule(Rule<S> rule, S data)
    {
        this.map.put(rule, data);
    }
}   


class EMailValidationRule implements Rule<String>
{
    private static final Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("email-regex");
    public void applyRule(String s) throws Exception
    {
        if(!emailPattern.matcher(s).matches())
            throw new Exception("Not a valid EMail");
    }
}
```

So the UserContact has to do the following for its validation purposes. This keeps the code compact (IMO).

```
class UserContact implements Validatable
{

    // some 
    // code
    // related to User Contact


    public void validate() throws Exception
    {
        MyValidator validator = new MyValidator();
        validator.addRule(new EMailValidationRule(), "developer@stackoverflow.com");
        validator.addRule(new PhoneValidationRule(), "+1234567890");
        validator.validate();
    }
}
```

I keep getting error like :

The method put(capture#5-of ? extends Rule, capture#6-of ?) in the type HashMap is not applicable 
     for the arguments (Rule, S)

Also is the above design good for doing validations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, although your encapsulation ensures it, the compiler can not be sure that the retrieved `Rule<...>` has a type argument of the same type as the retrieved data.

There is also the problem of not being able to insert a `Rule<T>` with data of a subtype of `T`. If you have `Rule<S> rule, S data` the types have to be an exact match. While a `Rule<S>` could handle a subtype of `S` just fine.

---

While `MyValidator` is a cool little class, I can't really see the point in having it. Especially because you create a new one every time you call `validate`. It would also be hard to cache because the rules are static (the same for every instance of the class) and the data comes from individual instances (I'd assume).

You could also just do this:

```
class UserContact implements Validatable
{

    // some 
    // code
    // related to User Contact

    // 1 rule instance for the entire class, not a new one per call to 'validate'
    private static EMailValidationRule emailRule = new EmailValidationRule();
    private static PhoneValidationRule phoneRule = new PhoneValidationRule();

    public void validate() throws Exception
    {
        emailRule.applyRule("developer@stackoverflow.com");
        phoneRule.applyRule("+1234567890");
    }
}
```

---

Never the less, here is a working version of `MyValidator`:

```
class MyValidator {
    private Map<Rule<?>, RuleNode<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void validate() throws Exception {
        for(RuleNode<?> node : map.values())
            node.apply();
    }

    public <T, D extends T> void addRule(Rule<T> rule, D data) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // unchecked, but safe due to encapsulation
        RuleNode<T> r = (RuleNode<T>) map.get(rule);
        if(r == null) {
            r = new RuleNode<T>(rule);
            map.put(rule, r);
        }

        r.add(data);
    }

    private static class RuleNode<T> { // Maintains that the rule and data are compatible
        private final Rule<T> rule;
        private final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

        public RuleNode(Rule<T> rule) {
            this.rule = rule;
        }

        public void add(T data) {
            list.add(data);
        }

        public void apply() throws Exception {
            for(T data : list)
                rule.applyRule(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `you overwrite data that was already there.` only if the rules are equal, this is a `HashMap` after all. It may be useful to separate validation rules for the same data type. So one rule could validate the email pattern and a second could ensure it isn't a duplicate. With your code, only one would be available. This isn't necessarily what was requested.

Comment: @Obicere ```It may be useful to separate validation rules for the same data type```, this is still possible. You have a class ```EMailvalidationRule implements Rule<String>``` and another class ```AnotherValidationRule implements Rule<String>```. They are different keys, so you could still have both.

Comment: Your first point does raise an interesting point, you can't have 2 rule instances of the same type that do different things (e.g. because of different instance fields). I had taken from OP's code that the intent was to have 1 rule instance per rule type, but that is also a weak point. See updated answer

Comment: The only thing I was concerned about was anonymous classes, but I guess that wasn't really an issue. Because you could do like `addRule(Rule.class, new Rule<String>() { /* ... */}, "foo");` and it could be messy. Anyway, dropping the `Class` portion is a better design choice and this looks a lot better now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the insights. Helps a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make a generic Version of the `MyValidator` Class

A generic class is defined with thss format:

> `class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { /* ... */ }`

Defining the class using generics you will specify the types you want to use in your class, in your case `<R extends Rule<S> ,S>`

```
class MyValidator<R extends Rule<S> ,S>{
    private HashMap<R ,S> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void validate() throws Exception{
        for(Rule<S> rule : map.keySet()){
            rule.applyRule(map.get(rule));
        }
    }
    public void addRule(R rule, S data){
        this.map.put(rule, data);
    }
}
```

Once done you just have to build a `MyValidator` of the desired type :

```
MyValidator<Rule<String>, String> validator = new MyValidator<>();
```

And finally add the rules matching the types of the validator :

```
validator.addRule(new EMailValidationRule(), "developer@stackoverflow.com");
```

So for example addind a phone validator your `UserContact` will looks like :

```
class PhoneValidationRule implements Rule<String>{
    private static final Pattern phonePattern = Pattern.compile("phone-regex");
    public void applyRule(String s) throws Exception{
        if(!phonePattern.matcher(s).matches())
            throw new Exception("Not a valid phone");
    }
}

class UserContact implements Validatable{
    public void validate() throws Exception{
        MyValidator<Rule<String>, String> validator = new MyValidator<>();
        validator.addRule(new EMailValidationRule(), "developer@stackoverflow.com");
        validator.addRule(new PhoneValidationRule(), "developer@stackoverflow.com");
        validator.validate();
    }
}
```

Comment: A very simple rule: Map<X, ?>.put(...) cannot be called, ever. "?" there means "some class that is distinct from any other class you can possibly have". So no value is ever good enough for the second argument of put(). This is different from get() which simply treats "?" as Object for the purpose of figuring the type it should return.